# I solved a regexp issue associated with IE9, but I'm not sure how or why it works

Tags: javascript, regex, browser, web, internet-explorer-9

**Background**

I have recently had a problem with a regular expression not working as expected in IE9. I tracked the issue down to a specific block inside the expression, namely [^].

```
var reg = /((?:abc.[^]*?)?test\s*(?:xyz)?\s*)[^]*?/;
```

**The problem**

```
var str = 'abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz';
var reg = /((?:abc.[^]*?)?test\s*(?:xyz)?\s*)[^]*?/;
alert(reg.exec(str));
```

In other words:

*Input:*

```
abc 123
abc 123
abc 123
test xyz
```

*Output*

```
Expected: ["abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz","abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz"]

Chrome: ["abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz","abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz"]

IE9: ["test xyz", "test xyz"] // Wrong!!!
```

**Attempted solution**

I found that the [^] block is causing the error. By simply switching [^] to [\S\s] I was able to attain the expected output in IE9.

```
var str = 'abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz';
var reg = /((?:abc.[\S\s]*?)?test\s*(?:xyz)?\s*)[\S\s]*?/;
alert(reg.exec(str));
```

*Output*

```
Expected: ["abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz","abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz"]

Chrome: ["abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz","abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz"]

IE9: ["abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz","abc 123\nabc 123\nabc 123\ntest xyz"]
```

**Question**

So what is the essential difference between [^] and [\S\s]? What is the problem here? Am I just dealing with an edge-case in the IE-javascript engine?

Comment: Looks like IE don't like _negated empty classes_, `[\S\s]` is nothing but it matches any character including _new lines_ which is excluded by `.`

Comment: i always used `[\w\W]`, is `[\s\S]` better or faster?

Comment: "If the first character in the square brackets is a caret (^), it matches any character except those following it in []". That is how it is defined in general with regular expressions. Here, we have an interesting edge case, with only ^  in []. I am not sure if this case is well defined. Different implementations may do it differently. [\s\S] means "match any space or non-space", so it matches any character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between `[^]` and `[\s\S]`. `[^]` exists in the Javascript specifications but IE9 doesn't handle it as many other Javascript features.

It seems that `[^]` is AFAIK particular to Javascript. I have never seen it in an other regex flavour. In other flavours `[^]` can be seen either as a syntax error or as an unclosed character class (in this case the closing bracket is not the end of the character class because it is immediately after the `^` and the class will eventually be closed at the next closing bracket if it exists).

Note that `[^]` and `[]` are allowed since the first time regex features were added to the language ([ECMA-262, 3rd edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) December 1999).

In ECMA-262 third edition specifications (15.10.2.13), you can read that a negative character class is defined like this:

```
CharacterClass :: [^ ClassRanges ]
```

where `ClassRanges` can be empty or not.

This definition is always the same in the [6th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-patterns) (June 2015).

Comment: Yes, using `[^]` to mean *anything, including newlines* was a deliberate choice, and it was a really, really bad idea.  Please don't use it.

Comment: @AlanMoore, why bad idea ? [\s\S] include also newline

Comment: The fact that a character class whatever the syntax includes the newline isn't a problem. `[^]` in Javascript may seems counter-intuitive for people who comes from other languages and vice-versa (why `[^]` is an unclosed character class with BRE or PHP). This syntax isn't standard at all. I don't know if this syntax is good or bad (`[\s\S]` may look like an ugly workaround and switching the dotall mode not handy, however the idea of a token for all chars is a good idea), whatever, this syntax exists for 16 years and it will be difficult to change it without breaking all old codes.

Comment: Yes, there is a need for a token that means *anything, including newlines*.  The original spec didn't include one, so the users came up with their own: `[\s\S]`.  Problem solved.  Adding `[^]` to the spec just created another problem, because its meaning is not at all obvious, and it's incompatible with other flavors.  `[^][^]` in JavaScript means *two of any characters (including newlines)*.  In most other flavors, it means *any one character except `]`, or `[`, or `^`*.  Yes, `[^]` is part of the language, and it's not going away.  I'm just saying, don't use it.

Comment: @AlanMoore: have you seen the new Perl 6 regex/grammar syntax? It uses the dot to match any characters without exceptions and `\N` (like in PCRE) to match all characters except new lines.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Yeah, they completely redesigned it in terms of what makes sense today instead of what's compatible with existing tools (like `grep`, which was only ever *applied* to one line at a time).  Must be nice...

Comment: @Alan Moore, Good example '[^][^]' that shows why [^] is problematic